# Merging and Sorting 2 dataframes and create another with one common column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames

**DF1:**

[image]

**DF2:**

[image]

The common column is Fin, but the DF1 Plo column should maintain its order and the data in DF2 should be inserted in between on the right side to create another DF like below, with DF1 on the left and DF2 on the right and the common column Fin in the middle

**Expected Output:**
[image]

i tried this

```
new=pd.concat([i.set_index('Fin') for i in [pdadata1,pdadata2]],axis=1, join='outer')
```

I am not sure on how to make the DF1 on the left and Fin in the middle, any help would be nice

Comment: Have you tried an outer merge: `new = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='Fin')`?

Comment: oh yes, that works, what should be done for sorting Fin with pol fixed on the left

Comment: How can i make the Plo fixed on left and sort things

Comment: I used the sort_values and fixed the Plo but it is not working as expected new1=new.sort_values(by=['Plo'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an "outer join". Look at the `merge` method with parameter `how='outer'`.

Comment: It is working, however i am not able to do sorting as asked in the question